# How to make image appear only when I hover on it

Tags: html, css, hover, mouseover

I want my image to appear only when I mouseover it and I tried putting this in the style section and it didn't work. Is this code right?

```
<style type=“text/css”>
img{opacity: 0;}
img:hover{opacity: 1;}
</style>
```

Comment: That is working correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/2ry3n45a/

Comment: It appears you are using unrecognised quotes. Try " instead of “

Comment: Just curiousity_ I'm wondering which software you're using to write your code....

Answer (score 8):

You are using the wrong type of quotation marks.

Change the `“text/css”` to `"text/css"`.

**Incorrect**

```
<style type=“text/css”>
  img {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
</style>
```

**Correct**

```
<style type="text/css">
  img {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I have no idea how you spotted this. Kudos.

Comment: i had it happen to me once many years ago when i copy pasted some code examples, the code worked outside of style tags but not in them. It was a lucky guess.